# Why is document.querySelector not working on pseudo element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am playing with pseudo elements and javascript but some how i can not style it using javascript.

```js
    var div = document.querySelector(":before");
    div.style["display"] ="none";
```

```css
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
}

div:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top:0;
    right:-100px;
    width:100px;
    height:100%;
    background:green;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

do anyone knows why this is not working?

Comment: Pseudo elements are not part of the content. They don't have any existence in DOM so you basicly can't manipulate something that doesn't exist

Comment: CSS Pseudo-classes will never return any elements, as specified in the Selectors API http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#grammar

Comment: Unfortunately you can only create pseudo elements (shadow elements) with `.createShadowRoot()` but you cannot access them.

Comment: The answer here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49106088/changing-pseudo-element-style-from-javascript) shows how you can use document.querySelector, just change the pseudo element to a span (if possible)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to style pseudo elements from javascript you have to use the CSSOM to inject the rules. It's not trivial, but it's possible.

```
var sheet = document.styleSheets[0]; //get style sheet somehow
var rules = sheet.rules; 
sheet.insertRule('div:before { display: none; }', rules.length);
```

[a slightly modified example from this article](http://www.polymer-project.org/articles/styling-elements.html)

[CCSOM Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model)

Comment: Great answer, +1 for the links.