# Apply css for pseudo elements using javascript

Tags: javascript

i am trying to add css for #sai:after using javascript like this. but this is not working.

```
$("#sai:before").css({"background":"dodgerblue"});
```

anyone know how to apply css using js

Comment: In the linked dup, the accepted answer is not useful, take a look at [vsync's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50782696/1169519) instead.

Comment: If the styles to attach are not dynamic, you can avoid overly complex solutions by creating the alternative (class)rules to the stylesheet, and then simply change the class of the element with JS.